# Add product to Cart with inventory validation

Tags: spring-boot, database-design, concurrency, system-design

During an interview I was asked a question stating "There is a product_inventory table with **product,quantity** column. There is one product in it with quantity 10. You have to design an add to cart functionality such that only 10 requests(Each requesting 1 quantity) should succeed and others should fail".

I had the following approaches to this problem

1. Use pessimistic locking to update the inventory table quantity as the requests come. This one had the disadvantage that if the
   number of requests coming in are too many than they might timeout
   which is not a good experience for user.
2. use Optimistic locking, so even if multiple simultaneous requests come in, only one request
   will successfully update theinventory and for ones which get the optimisticException, they can
   be retried once before sending an error to UI.
3. Using trigger before update to check if inventory quantity - requested Qty should be >= 0

Are these valid approaches for this problem. On googling I get shopping websites as results, nothing much on the design of this. How do the websites that conduct Product online Sale handle the request to add to cart for so many simultaneous requests?

**UPDATE:**

Found this blog post that addresses exactly this problem

https://codingsight.com/the-lost-update-problem-in-concurrent-transactions/

Comment: 4) Process the order and hope new inventory comes in before the order is packaged.

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/transaction-iso.html
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isolation_(database_systems)